# create schema for imported csv in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, import

i have a csv that looks like this:

```
    Number,Date,ClientName,ClientSurname,ClientAge,Option1,Option2
    1,01/01/2015,John,Foo,24,30,
```

using mongoimport i get

```
    {
    "_id":ObjectID(""),
    "Number":1,
    "date":"01/01/2015",
    "ClientName":"John",
    "ClientSurname":"Foo",
    "ClientAge":24,
    "Option1":30,
    "Option2": "", 
     }
```

what i want is

```
    {
    "_id":ObjectID(""),
    "Number":1,
    "date":"01/01/2015",
    "Client":[{
        "ClientName":"John",
        "ClientSurname":"Foo",
        "ClientAge":24,
    }]
    "Options":["30"] 
     }
```

i tried with validation prior to importing but didn't work,is it possible to change the schema as i want now that i have the data imported,or should i use another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use dotted field names in the CSV header, `mongoimport` will automatically create the sub-document for you. However, this doesn't work with arrays.

For example:

```
$ cat test.csv
Number,Date,Client.Name,Client.Surname,Client.Age,Option.0,Option.1
1,01/01/2015,John,Foo,24,30,

$ mongoimport -d test -c test --drop --headerline --type=csv test.csv

> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a4f0768c481930d7c589a41"),
  "Number": 1,
  "Date": "01/01/2015",
  "Client": {
    "Name": "John",
    "Surname": "Foo",
    "Age": 24
  },
  "Option": {
    "0": 30,
    "1": ""
  }
}
```

To get the `Option` array, you would need to do some post-processing.

Alternatively, you can ingest the CSV file using a separate script, and insert into MongoDB using a driver (e.g. Pymongo). This way, you have total control over the structure of the generated document.

Comment: thank you, what if i want to reference instead of embedding the client? Need to use Pymongo also for that or is there any other way?

Comment: @doe more complex import requirements would require custom import code, since `mongoimport` assumes your data is one-document-per-line.